# Multivariant tests goals vs a page visit

Tags: content-testing

What is the best approach for setting up a goal to measure the success of a component test within Sitecore? Let's say I have two components in my test and they have a different colored button. I have both buttons linking to the same page so how can I tell what button was clicked more (what variant was more successful for my test)? Do I need the buttons to link to different pages (just a copy of the original page) with separate goals? Also, how can I differentiate clicks from my test vs someone just visiting the page?

Comment: In your scenario with different button colors, you'll want to link to the same page - with that page registering the goal. The result of the test should then be calculated Sitecore with no additonal work from you.

Comment: @sestocker so Sitecore will know the difference between each button as well as a page visit outside of my test?

Comment: as long as you are doing the button colors via MVT in Sitecore, it will all just work. See the following link for the basics: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/analyzing__reporting/experience_optimization__content_testing/setting_up_tests/create_an_ab_or_multivariate_test_in_the_experience_editor

Comment: @sestocker It looks like you have a solution for this question. It'd be very useful for future visitors if you created an answer describing the solution in more detail.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Abandoned/Inconclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Leave it as a single page with a goal associated. Then...

1. Create a new version of the component with the second color (if you are an admin user create a new version of the page first to ensure you trigger draft workflow state)
2. Submit through workflow
3. Approver should choose "approve with test" to trigger mvt dialog.
4. Follow prompts to create the test of the two buttons.

Edit: just noticed sestocker gave the same basic info in comments.  If he can create an answer rather than comment give him the credit as he was first.